# In MongoDB how to query an embeded array which has same key name

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, out

```
{
    '_id': 103, 
    'name': 'Fleta Duplantis', 
    'scores': [
        {'score': 84.37799696030743, 'type': 'exam'}, 
        {'score': 15.95792143439528, 'type': 'quiz'}, 
        {'score': 77.80745176713172, 'type': 'homework'}
    ]
}
```

I have 200 documents
in this, I need to calculate the average for each test type and also need to check if the score is above 40 in each category

`db.Stumarks.find({'scores':{'$elemMatch':{'type':'exam','score':{'$gte':40}}}})`

I tried this, i am getting it for one category. but I couldn't store this result in a separate collection using the `$out` command

Comment: Please provide your requested results for the sample document

Comment: `$out` is available within an aggregation pipeline, you are doing a simple find query. It will not work.

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mjpNjH1W8QA) what you need? If it is I can explain it better in an answer.